# Unable to invoke WSO2 API Manager 1.10 admin services

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have enabled the admin services from `carbon.xml` for API Manager and extracted the wsdl successfully. Now I am trying to invoke the service `RemoteTenantManagerService` using SOAP UI. I have loaded the wsdl in SOAP UI and also provided the Basic authentication Username/Password as `admin/admin`. But I am getting following message back. Port for API Manager is Offset `1`

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.um.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getAllTenants/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) /services/RemoteTenantManagerService.RemoteTenantManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of transports, PassThrough and servlet. The admin services are exposed through servlet transport. Hence those must be invoked using servlet transport port.

For ex:- `https://{host}:9443/services/RemoteTenantManagerService`

In your case you have set offset to the "1" so please call the service using the URL `https://{host}:9444/services/RemoteTenantManagerService`

The generated WSDL contains the endpoint with Passthrough port hence soapUI shows it as the default endpoint. Please change the port to servlet port (your case it should be 9444) and run again.